# operator<< overload for a member type in a template class in C++

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading, type-members

In the code below, I have a template class with a **member type**(struct Element). I want to overload operator<< for that **member type**. However, the code won't compile.

I would appreciate it if someone could point out where I am going wrong?

```
include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// fwd decl
template<class T> class CC;

// operator<< overload template for member type CC<T>::Element
template<class T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const typename CC<T>::Element& elm) {
    return os << elm.val1 << "/" << elm.val2;
}

template<class T>
class CC
{
public:
    struct Element {    // type member
        int val1;
        int val2;
    };

    template<typename U>
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const typename CC<U>::Element& elm);
};

int main() {
    CC<int>::Element elm{0,0};
    cout << elm << endl;     // does not compile due to this!
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Template arguments can't be deduced from a nested entity (the short explanation: the type may be seame for different template instantiations). That is, the declaration

```
template<typename U>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const typename CC<U>::Element& elm);
```

whether for a `friend` or not is never considered because the type `U` can't be deduced. You can fix the problem by making the `friend` operator a non-template:

```
// ...
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Element& elm) { ... }
// or
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const CC<T>::Element& elm) { ... }
// ...
```

The function will need to be implemented in its declaration, though.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. I have tried both of your suggestions, but the code still doesn't compile. I get this error: _undefined reference to `operator<<(std::ostream&, CC<int>::Element const&)'_

Comment: Scratch my previous comment. My mistake. I am supposed to write the implementation as you have mentioned, which I didn't. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that in following code

```
 ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const typename CC<T>::Element& elm) {
```

`Element` is in non-deduced context. As a result, template argument can not be deduced. And since a call to `operator<<` with explicit template argument would be really ugly (if possible at all), I suggest to change the overall coding pattern.

For example, you can make `elm` to be deduced template argument, like

```
template<typename E>
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const E& elm);
```

And than extract actual `U` from E using specialized struct.

Comment: Note that this function templates conceptually declares an unconstrained template. Since it is located within another class it won't be looked up in many contexts and it can only be found using ADL. I'd still avoid using unconstrained templates when implementing a customization point.

Comment: @DietmarKühl, I certainly see your point and I am not arguing about it at all. Your solution is better - this is why I upvoted it :)